# Auto-update views.py

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I created a function for editing tables
but it is done by url address "get/by/int:pk/" and I need it to be done automatically after saving in Django Admin panel. How can I do that?

```
def obj(request, pk,):
reg = Registration.objects.get(pk=pk)
room = Rooms.objects.get(pk=pk)
if reg.room_bool == True:
    room.room_bool = True
    room.save()

if reg.room_bool == False:
    room.room_bool = False
    room.save()
```

how can this be implemented

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want the update to be done automatically and not through the url get/by/int:pk/